# how do i setup my maven pom for different environment builds?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have 3 environments:

1. local (dev)
2. staging
3. production

each environment uses different properties files (e.g. to specify jdbc properties). currently, my maven project builds a war file. could someone please give me some guidance on how to modify the `pom.xml` file so that i can specify different builds?

for example, if i need to build the war file for stage, what do i need to do to the pom.xml file to make this happen so that the staging properties files is used (included in the war)?

let me be a little more clear with my build. i am using spring mvc, so i can toggle which environment (e.g. properties files) is present. the way this is accomplished is by setting the context parameter in web.xml as follows.

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
 <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>
```

so, basically, if i use maven profiles, how do i swap out this parameter value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define different environment profiles in your pom.xml

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>environment</name>
        <value>test</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

or give it a specific id/name like this

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>profile-1</id>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

and run `mvn` using `mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -Pprofile-1`

You can find more information [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: i think that's the path i want to go down, using profiles, but the document doesn't really tell how to change parameter values (see modified post) or swap out files. it is almost like i need a way to express in the pom.xml this type of logic: if profile=dev, then set spring.profiles.active=dev.

Comment: You can use in your spring config file  `<param-value>${spring.config}</param-value>` and define a parameter inside each profile `<spring.config>[your env]</spring.config>`

Ensure you're processing your spring config file as a resource in maven, btw