# Maven building for different environments

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a Java project that currently builds nicely with Maven.  But, I'm using an Ant script to do other tasks that I think Maven could also do.  To simplify the build workflow, I'd like to get Maven doing everything I need.  All this is automated with Jenkins.

The challenge is that I want Maven to build a single artifact and deploy it to multiple environments on-demand via command line.  Currently, I do this by building with Maven, then using an Ant script that will create a copy of the WAR artifact with some files changed depending on the environment I chose.  This adapts for things like JDBC connection strings, properties files, etc. that are different in each environment.

I understand Maven can use profiles, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22230701/3347).  However, I'm stuck on figuring out how to make a secondary WAR file for the environment.  e.g. I start with "myproject.war" created from the build step, and I want to create "myproject-dev.war", then deploy it to the dev Tomcat server.  I figure I can use the antrun maven plugin to make the file changes, but I don't know how to hook it into the lifecycle.  Then, I'd need to use the tomcat plugin to deploy.

Any suggestions on how this could be configured?

Comment: what differs in both wars? webcontent?

Comment: Please, don't abuse profiles. You should have 1 war and separate environment configurations. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931181/hoe-to-pass-value-to-maven-pom-xml-at-rum-time-from-java-file how this should be combined.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume you have a structure like the following (just as an example)

```
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   |-- java
    |   |-- resources
    |   |-- environment
    |   |   |-- test
    |   |   |   `-- database.properties
    |   |   |-- qa
    |   |   |   `-- database.properties
    |   |   `-- production
    |   |       `-- database.properties
    |   `-- webapp
```

You can define a assembly descriptor like the following:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

  <id>test</id>
  <formats>
    <format>war</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/environment/test/</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Furthermore you need a maven-assembly-plugin configuration like the following:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/test.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</project>
```

If you add a separate assembly-descriptor for each environment and add a line with the descriptor you can create with a single call the packages for each environment.
One drawback of this you have several assembly-descriptors which are aside from a few lines identical.

So going more you can use the [iterator-maven-plugin](https://github.com/khmarbaise/iterator-maven-plugin/) to reduce the configuration and mainenance hassle like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>iterator</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <items>
          <item>test</item>
          <item>prod</item>
          <item>dev</item>
        </items>

        <pluginExecutors>
          <pluginExecutor>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <goal>single</goal>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/iterator.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </pluginExecutor>
        </pluginExecutors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

So furthermore you need an appropriate assembly descriptor like this:

```xml
<assembly
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

  <id>${item}</id>
  <formats>
    <format>war</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/environment/${item}/</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/environment/${item}/</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

This makes it simple and convenient to maintain such a build. A full working example can looked at the [integration tests of iterator-maven-plugin](https://github.com/khmarbaise/iterator-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it/mavenAssemblyPluginWithPropertiesTest).

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Iterator or Assembly plugins, so thank you for pointing them out.  However, this configuration takes the approach of creating specialized packages for each environment at build time.  This creates a large load on the build server for both compile time and storage of many artifacts.

My plan is to store one artifact, the environment agnostic WAR file.  At deploy time, I want to modify the artifact to specialize it for the target environment and deploy it.  This specialized artifact is not retained.

Comment: Anyway, it seems I should keep the environment specialization outside of Maven.  Ant seems to manage this quite well as a post-build step.

Comment: Hello @khmarbaise,
I try your pom and assembly ... But building my code, I got this error :
`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project Test: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.`

Comment: First you should use a more recent version of maven-assembly-plugin second you should add file `src/assembly/iterator.xml` as described above...